# SQLiteDatabse giving NullPointerException

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I am getting NullPointerException in the marked in the code.

The code typically reads a text file in raw folder in the project and inserts the contents in the table of the database. The text file in the raw folder contains a list of english words, for spell checking purpose. Could anyone help me regarding this matter.

```
public class WordsDB
{
    private static final String FTS_WORD_DB="FTS_WORD_DB";
private static final String WORD="WORD";
private static final String FTS_WORD_DB_CREATE="CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "+FTS_WORD_DB+" USING ft3 ("+WORD+");";
private static final String WORD_DATABASE="WORD_DATABSE";
private static final int DATABSE_VERSION=1;
private WordsDBLoadHelper helper;
public static SQLiteDatabase wordDb;

public WordsDB(Context context)
{
    helper=new WordsDBLoadHelper(context);
}

public void load()
{
    helper.loadWordDb();
}

public class WordsDBLoadHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{   
    public WordsDBLoadHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, WORD_DATABASE, null, DATABSE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        wordDb=db;
        wordDb.execSQL(FTS_WORD_DB_CREATE);
    }

    public void loadWordDb()
    {
        Resources resource=SearchDict.context.getResources();
        InputStream is=resource.openRawResource(R.raw.wordlist);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        try
        {
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                addWord(line.trim());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(null, e.getStackTrace().toString(), e);
        }
    }

    public void addWord(String line)
    {
        try
        {
            ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
            values.put(WORD, line);
            wordDb.insert(FTS_WORD_DB, null, values);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(null, e.getStackTrace().toString(), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {   
    }
}
}
```

Is there any faster method to create table and insert values into it. The above procedure takes about more than a hour to insert values in the database because the text file contains more than 3 lakh words.
Is it possible to create the database once and store it permanently so that it is possible to retrieve values without recreating the database again and again when the project runs.

Comment: Where is your progressDialog? I can't see it in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

In Sqlite inserts are generally quite fast, but commits are slow. You're not using a transaction so after each insert sqlite does a commit.

```
wordDB.startTransaction();
try {

    /*while loop*/

    wordDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
 db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: The exception is still being thrown.